# Greek characters insert mysqldb via TextCtrl ERROR

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, wxpython, mysql-python

I have create in MySQdb a DB with a table named example,in this table i want to save a name,
this name is in Greek language.My problem is thw follown when i try to save the name instantly without use textctrl, its ok but when i use textctrl i take error.Look the code:
Can anyone hel me please i have try encoding in utf-8,decoding in utf-8, to unicode but nothing.

```
import os
import math
import random
import wx
import MySQLdb 
import sys
APP_SIZE_X = 500
APP_SIZE_Y = 300

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, wx.DefaultPosition, size=(APP_SIZE_X, APP_SIZE_Y))

        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1,style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)

        wx.StaticText(panel, -1,'Name', (10, 55),style=wx.LEFT)
        self.name = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, '', (110, 55), (120, -1))

        save = wx.Button(panel, 1, 'Save', (70, 215),(130,-1))
        save.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.OnSaveAsFile)

        quitbtn = wx.Button(panel, 1, 'Quit', (250, 215),(130,-1))
        quitbtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.OnQuit)

    def OnSaveAsFile(self, event):

        idis="000"
        newname=self.name.GetValue()



        db=MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",use_unicode="True",charset="utf8",user="root",passwd="root",db="test")
        cursor=db.cursor()

        sql="""INSERT INTO TB_EXAMPLE(name) VALUES("%s","%s")"""%(idis,newname)


        try:


            cursor.execute(sql)

            db.commit()
            print 'save ok'
        except:

            print 'no save'
            db.rollback()

    def OnQuit(self,e):

        self.Close()








class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyFrame(None, -1, 'form1.py')
        frame.Show(True)
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        return True

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the unicode version of wxPython? That might just fix this problem. Or you could take a look at the following two links:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/RecipesI18n
- http://wiki.wxpython.org/Internationalization

You might be able to fake it just by doing something like this:

```
newname= u"%s" % self.name.GetValue()
```

Comment: Then try asking on the wxPython mailing list. There are several guys on there that know how to do stuff like this.

Comment: I was doing a terrible mistake i don't use unicode version of wxpython, now i use its all ok thanks men!!!

Answer (score 0):

Does it make any difference if you let the db module do the parameter substitution instead of having Python do it? (This is much safer anyway if you are inserting user entered values.) For example:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO TB_EXAMPLE(name) VALUES(%s,%s)", (idis,newname))
```

From reading the MySQLdb docs it sounds like that will also auto-convert to/from unicode when the charset connect parameter is set.

Comment: Robin has a point. Personally, I use SQLAlchemy for most of my database interactions.